# Getting contact sensor/bumper Gazebo plugin to work

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone had success with this? That is, creating a contact sensor/ bumper in urdf and connecting it to the Gazebo plugin described here (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Bumper), and then receiving the messages you'd expect on the defined topic.

My Gazebo code is:

```
<gazebo reference="bump_sensor">
<sensor name="main_bumper" type="contact">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>15.0</updateRate>
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    <contact>
       <collision>bump_sensor_collision</collision>
    </contact>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_bumper_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">   
        <bumperTopicName>bumper_vals</bumperTopicName>
        <frameName>world</frameName>
    </plugin>
</sensor>
</gazebo>
```

The model code is

```
<joint name="bumper_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz=".2 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="bump_sensor"/>   </joint>

 <link name="bump_sensor">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
         <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with above. The topic bumper_vals is created and I can look at the messages to it via rostopic echo. They are in the expected gazebo_msgs/ContactState format. (or is it ContactsState?)

The point is that the states[] array is always empty even on an obvious collision.

Heaps of people seem to have had problems with bumpers (especially in simulation) and I don't see any clear cut answer. Why isn't there an effort to get this to work?
If you know anything about robotics, then a contact sensor is the most basic thing you need to have working.
Cameras, laser sensors re great, but the contact sensor is  (should be) the simple, reliable backup that gets you out of trouble. And you can do a lot with it alone - e.g investigate and test path planning algorithms in spaces with obstacles, which is my project.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Rob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246448/getting-contact-sensor/bumper-gazebo-plugin-to-work/) by [RobB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28121/robb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neckutrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/27626/neckutrek/) on 2016-12-13**:
I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need apply the name attribute to your collision tag such as:

```
<collision name="bump_sensor_collision">
...
</collision>
```

This should make it work. However if specifying in urdf or xacro you may still have an issue in that the sensor doesn't output anything. In that case suffix the

```
<contact>
       <collision>bump_sensor_collision</collision>
</contact>
```

with a `_collision`, such that it reads:

```
<contact>
       <collision>bump_sensor_collision_collision</collision>
</contact>
```

This trick was due to how the sdf is generated from the urdf file, in that it was appending a _collision to the name attribute of the collision specification.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-03-01**:
it can be more complicated that a simple _collision add but this is indeed the general idee ;)
More details in the link in my answer ;)

**Comment by [littleghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/33922/littleghost/) on 2018-06-27**:
This trick is very important. I spend a week on this. Really don't know why gazebo not give a demo directly.

**Comment by [HaiSanCamRanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/51553/haisancamranh/) on 2020-02-18**:
I can not solve the problem, I also added the _collision, but it did not work, here is my xml in turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro

```
<gazebo reference="bump_sensor">
    <sensor name="main_bumper" type="contact">
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>15.0</updateRate>
        <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
        <contact>
            <collision>bump_sensor_collision_collision</collision>
        </contact>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_bumper_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
            <bumperTopicName>bumper_vals</bumperTopicName>
            <frameName>world</frameName>
        </plugin>
    </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

here is my full bumper xml: https://ideone.com/Exwz1Z

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2020-02-18**:
This is why I didn't only say to add collision but to check the full explanation on my answer .... It has been later clarified for the simple case and this has become the accepted answer but the full explanation lie in my post in answer.gazebosim linked in my answer below.

**Comment by [HaiSanCamRanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/51553/haisancamranh/) on 2020-02-18**:
@TTDM, thank you a lot, that is my mistake because of not checking your specific and wondrous answer. By checking the sdf with (gz sdf -p turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro), I found that your supplementary note is likely my problem. After seeing the collision name in the sdf file, I modified the turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro
But the state output is still empty, I have checked by parse to sdf again and in the sdf file:

```
<collision name='base_footprint_fixed_joint_lump__bump_sensor_collision_collision_1'>
    <pose frame=''>0.05 0 0.03 0 -0 0</pose>
    ...
  </collision>
```

and the sensor tag,

```
<sensor name='main_bumper' type='contact'>
        <contact>
          <collision>base_footprint_fixed_joint_lump__bump_sensor_collision_collision_1</collision>
          <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
        </contact>
        ...
```

Did I miss or do anything wrong? here is my turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro: https://ideone.com/XGmhIQ
Again, thank you a lot!

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2020-02-19**:
Hi, you forgot to declare "update rate" and "always on" on this last file. Also, in my code, i have them twice, once in the  tag and once inside the  tag; even if i'm not sure its useful (but since i didn't tested it i still gives you the differences i see).
Here is my code :

`bumper_vals
            world
            true
            1000.0
        
          true
          1000.
          
            hummingbird/base_link_fixed_joint_lump__mav_collision_box_collision`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved a problem which was close to this one,( you can check here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15095/gazebo-contact-sensor-added-to-a-robot-link-in-urdf-file-is-not-working-as-expected/ ) and I wonder if itsn't the same for you :

You call a "bump_sensor_collision" inside the gazebo flag to define the collision and you assume that it is created by the declaration of a collision inside the "bump_sensor"  ( which it should be ).
However i found that the first name can be modified with a few supplementary informations so I invite you to check on the final sdf if your two names are identical and if they aren't to change the name inside the  flag to make is match the collision in the .

More information on how to do so are in the first link.

TTDM

---

Originally posted by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) with karma: 267 on 2017-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28121/robb/) on 2017-02-27**:
Cheers. I'll give it a try.
Rob